# Returning data frame entries based on max date and/or max values (COVID-19 data example)

Tags: r

```
df <- read.csv ('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ulklc/covid19-timeseries/master/countryReport/raw/rawReport.csv',
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I found this code which finds countries that reported the highest number of deaths and recovered by region were found in this code.

```
    yesterday <- function() Sys.Date() - 1L
    yesterday()
    # [1] "if it doesn't work yesterday()-1  do it" 

    library(tidyverse)
    death_df <- df %>%
    filter(as.Date(day) == yesterday()) %>%
    group_by(region) %>%
    filter(death == max(death)) %>%
    select(Date = day,
         countryName,
         region,
         death,
         recovered)

     recovered_df <- df %>%
     filter(as.Date(day) == yesterday()) %>%
    group_by(region) %>%
    filter(recovered == max(recovered)) %>%
    select(Date = day,
         countryName,
         region,
         death,
         recovered)

    full_df <- bind_rows(death_df, recovered_df)
```

However, I need to find the countries that report the most death and recovered to the world in general.

Here is the output I am looking for:

```
date            countryName       death        recovered
2020/05/06       united State   **19580**        500
2020/05/06       İran             11500        **98567**
```

Note that these values are not real.

The data set is updated daily. However, it may not have been updated for 1 -2 days. let's pay attention to this.

Answer (score 1):

The code below will select the record with the max daily `death` and max daily `recovered` for the max `date` in the data.

```
## call the dplyr library
library(dplyr)
## read the data into R
df <- read.csv ('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ulklc/covid19-timeseries/master/countryReport/raw/rawReport.csv', stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
## determine the max date contained within the data
max.date <- df[which.max(as.Date(df$day)),"day"]
## copy the data to preserve original
df1 <- df 
## filter the data to only entries from the max day
df1 <- filter(df1, as.Date(date, "%Y/%m/%d") == as.Date(max.date))
## determine the entry with the most deaths
max.deaths <- df1[which.max(df1$death),]
## format the number of deaths as given in the example
max.deaths$death <- paste0("**",max.deaths$death,"**")
## determine the entry with the most recovered
max.recovered <- df1[which.max(df1$recovered),]
## format the number recovered to match the format of the example
max.recovered$recovered <- paste0("**",max.recovered$recovered,"**")
## create a data frame containing our max death and max recovered entries
max.records <- rbind(max.deaths, max.recovered)
## attach a column with the max date which corresponds to the date of the entries selected
max.records$date <- max.date
## organize the data as shown in the example
max.records <- select(max.records, c("day","countryName","death","recovered"))
```

And this code will calculate aggregate (or total) deaths as `totalDeaths` and aggregate recovered as `totalRecovered` for each country.  It then returns the record with the max `totalDeath` and max `totalRecovered` with the max date within the data.

```
## call the dplyr library
library(dplyr)
## read the data into R
df <- read.csv ('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ulklc/covid19-timeseries/master/countryReport/raw/rawReport.csv', stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
## determine the max date contained within the data
max.date <- df[which.max(as.Date(df$day)),"day"]
## copy the data to preserve the original
df1 <- df 
## group the data by countries
df1 <- group_by(df1, countryName)
## sum the death and recovered of each country
df1 <- summarise(df1, totalDeaths = sum(death), totalRecovered = sum(recovered))
## ungroup your data to avoid errors
df1 <- ungroup(df1)
## determine country with most total deaths reported
max.deaths <- df1[which.max(df1$totalDeaths),]
## format death numbers to match example
max.deaths$totalDeaths <- paste0("**",max.deaths$totalDeaths,"**")
## determine country with most total recovered reported
max.recovered <- df1[which.max(df1$totalRecovered),]
## format recovered numbers to match example
max.recovered$totalRecovered <- paste0("**",max.recovered$totalRecovered,"**")
## create a data frame containing our max entries
max.records <- rbind(max.deaths, max.recovered)
## attach a column with the max date which corresponds to the most current date the data reports
max.records$date <- max.date
## organize the data as shown in the example
max.records <- select(max.records, c("day","countryName","death","recovered"))
```

Note: both methods rely upon the `dplyr` R package.  `dplyr` can be installed by running `install.packages(dplyr)` in R or RStudio.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is an approach to calculate the information you request for every day using `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
result <- df %>% group_by(day) %>% 
  filter(death == max(death) | recovered == max(recovered)) %>%
  mutate(death = case_when(death == max(death) ~ paste0("**",death[death == max(death)],"**"),
                           TRUE ~ as.character(death)),
         recovered = case_when(recovered == max(recovered) ~ paste0("**",recovered[recovered == max(recovered)],"**"),
                           TRUE ~ as.character(recovered)))
result %>%
  filter(day == "2020/04/06")
# A tibble: 2 x 9
# Groups:   day [1]
  day        countryCode countryName region   lat   lon confirmed recovered death    
  <chr>      <chr>       <chr>       <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>     <int> <chr>     <chr>    
1 2020/04/06 CN          China       Asia    35   105       81708 **77029** 3331     
2 2020/04/06 IT          Italy       Europe  42.8  12.8    132547 22837     **16523**
```