# Get date from dataset

Tags: r

```
 df <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ulklc/covid19- 
 timeseries/master/countryReport/raw/rawReport.csv')
 df$countryName = as.character(df$countryName)
```

I processed the dataset.

How can I find the countries that report the most patients, death and recovery in one day?

**Examples:**

1 June 2020 the country that reported the most deaths, 1 june the country that reported the case and 1 June the country that reported the most recoved

Comment: Hello Furkan, welcome to SO. Could you please show us what you have tried so far. It is hard to help you when we do not know where exactly your problem lies. Please help us helping you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code uses the `dplyr` R package to create a data frame called `records` that contains the data you desire.  Make sure you have `dplyr` installed by running `install.package("dplyr")` in R or RStudio.

```
## call the dplyr library
library(dplyr)
## read in your data to R
df <- read.csv ('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ulklc/covid19-timeseries/master/countryReport/raw/rawReport.csv', stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
## set the date you wish to query max records for
set.date <- "2020-06-01"
## copy the data to preserve the original
df1 <- df 
## filter the records to only those that match the specified date
df1 <- filter(df1, as.Date(date, "%Y/%m/%d") == as.Date(set.date))
## determine which country had the most confirmed on the specified day
max.confirmed <- df1[which.max(df1$confirmed),]
## format the record to identify it as the record with most confirmed
max.confirmed$confirmed <- paste0("**",max.confirmed$confirmed,"**")
## determine which country had the most deaths on the specified day
max.deaths <- df1[which.max(df1$death),]
## format the record to identify it as the record with most deaths
max.deaths$death <- paste0("**",max.deaths$death,"**")
## determine which country had the most recovered on the specified day
max.recovered <- df1[which.max(df1$recovered),]
## format the record to identify it as the record with most recovered
max.recovered$recovered <- paste0("**",max.recovered$recovered,"**")
## create the reocrds data frame to contain your max records
records <- rbind(max.confirmed, max.deaths, max.recovered)
```

You can update the date you wish to select by by changing `"2020-06-01"` to the date you desire to query max death and recovered for.  Make sure to use the `"YYYY-MM-DD"` format.

Alternatively, instead of manually updating the code, you can use the `readline()` function to ask the user to input the date they would like to query max data for.

ADDED (based on comments)
If you want to use today's data (or if today's data is not available the most recent data) you can use the code below:

```
## call the dplyr library
library(dplyr)
## read the data into R
df <- read.csv ('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ulklc/covid19-timeseries/master/countryReport/raw/rawReport.csv', stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
## determine the max date contained within the data
max.date <- df[which.max(as.Date(df$day)),"day"]
## copy the data to preserve original
df1 <- df 
## filter the data to only entries from the max day
df1 <- filter(df1, as.Date(date, "%Y/%m/%d") == as.Date(max.date))
## determine the entry with the most deaths
max.deaths <- df1[which.max(df1$death),]
## format the number of deaths as given in the example
max.deaths$death <- paste0("**",max.deaths$death,"**")
## determine the entry with the most recovered
max.recovered <- df1[which.max(df1$recovered),]
## format the number recovered to match the format of the example
max.recovered$recovered <- paste0("**",max.recovered$recovered,"**")
## create a data frame containing our max death and max recovered entries
max.records <- rbind(max.deaths, max.recovered)
## attach a column with the max date which corresponds to the date of the entries selected
max.records$date <- max.date
## organize the data as shown in the example
max.records <- select(max.records, c("day","countryName","death","recovered"))
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: thank you for the answer, so can we do this for the active day?

Comment: @FurkanUnal I'm not sure what you mean by active day, but you can  input any date contained within your data and the above code will work.  The data appears to be updated daily, with the most current entry being the day before.  If you want to automatically use the most recent date contained in the file you should refer to the answer I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61681420/producing-daily-data-in-the-dataset-and-comparing-with-other-days/62157720#62157720).  If these answers helped, please vote up on them.  Best wishes!

Comment: hello. active day=today

Comment: The added code will return the requested data using today, and if today's data is not available it will use the most recent.  If this helps, please give my answer an up vote (as it helps me out).  Best wishes!